# GCP Google Cloud - When hosting microsites on GCP, what is the most efficient way to handle SSL Certs for HTTPs

Tags: ssl-certificate, https, google-cloud-platform

My product built on GCP creates microsites. They are served by a Google Cloud Function connected to a GCP Load balancer. My customer's want to point their own domain names to my product's microsites.

Considering this could be hundreds of thousands to millions of domains: What is the most efficient way to generate and manage SSL certs that scales on GCP?

From reading the technical documentation (please correct me if I'm wrong):

- Each Google-managed SSL certificate can contain 100 domains.
- Each Load Balancer Frontend Can have 15 Certs.
- Each Load Balancer can have 1 static IP address and 1 https frontend.

Therefore each IP address is limited to 1,500 domains across 15 Certs?

```
If I had 500,000 users, this would mean I would need:
 1. 334 IP Addresses?
 2. 334 Load Balancers?
 3. 334 Frontends?
 4. 5,000 Certs?
```

It seems like Google doesn't support nearly that many certs or IP Addresses.

So my questions are:

1. is this the best way to scale the number of google managed certs?
2. am I missing something in my estimates and understanding of the quotas?
3. Is there a limit to the number of Static IP addresses / certs / load balancers a google project can have preventing scaling to that number of users with custom domains?
4. Is there another approach entirely?

Comment: Interesting scenario. I'd recommend to ask a sales-representative at Google to get exact information about this.

Answer (score 0):

Answer your questions:

What is the most efficient way to generate and manage SSL certs that scales on GCP?

Since GCP does not have a kind of "SSL Manage Console", the only way to manage the certificates is on each Load Balancer.

Therefore each IP address is limited to 1,500 domains across 15 Certs?

Yes, you are right, and is not possible to increase this limit.

If I had 500,000 users, this would mean I would need?

It is correct, based on the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/quotas?hl=ro) that you have already reviewed.

Is this the best way to scale the number of google managed certs?

Yes, nowadays, is the only way to manage the SSL certificates on GCP.

Am I missing something in my estimates and understanding of the quotas?

No, your understanding is correct about SSL certificates and IP Addresses quotas.

Is there a limit to the number of Static IP addresses / certs / load balancers a google project can have preventing scaling to that number of users with custom domains?

There is a Quota limit also for the Static IP Address available, you will need to request a Quota increase. For more reference please review on your console [Regional Static IP addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com&metric=%22Static%20IP%20addresses%22&_ga=2.245886528.59865663.1612534683-97927293.1588337573) and [Global Static IP addresses](https://console.cloud.google.com/admin/quotas?service=compute.googleapis.com&metric=%22Static%20IP%20addresses%20global%22&_ga=2.245886528.59865663.1612534683-97927293.1588337573)

Is there another approach entirely?

There is no currently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm in a similar situation as you. I haven't tried to create a POC for this yet, but here is a thought I had for something that could work:

Instead of managing the SSL certs at the Load Balancer, you can run nginx servers that have virtual hosts set up for each of the domains you are servicing. nginx supports a standard called SNI. This allows you to serve SSL certs for multiple hostnames from a single IP. From what I've read, there are no hard limits on how many domains you could serve like this. The only limits are the nginx memory requirements for the virtual hosts and the SSL certs.

You would still need to figure out how to add new virtual hosts and load the ssl certificates into the nginx servers.

I'm also not entirely what you would need to do in the case that you needed more than a single nginx server (you will).

Also, you can still use the Load Balancers in front of nginx if you needed to. You would just need to set them up as TCP load balancers instead of HTTP ones.

EDIT - A link from nginx stating there are no limits on v-hosts or ssl certs: https://www.nginx.com/faq/is-there-a-limit-to-the-number-of-virtual-hosts-or-ssl-certificates-that-i-can-configure-in-nginx-plus/

Comment: Doing some more reading on this subject - I think that Traefik might have the functionality you're looking for. https://doc.traefik.io/traefik-enterprise/

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm going to look into this more and will report back with hopefully a success story.

Comment: You're welcome! Do keep me posted; I have a project with similar requirements coming up and would like to know if this worked for you.